# How to create the manifest file for the Chatbot in microsoft teams?

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

[image]I created nlp chatbot using the botbuilder sample and I deployed to azure also. It is working fine in azure and also in emulator. I want to add this bot to the microsoft teams by creating the manifest file.
But I am not getting how to create it, I used App Studio for this still I am getting error.

Error: "something went wrong"

Comment: App Studio is the right tool for sure. Can you tell us when you're getting this error?

Comment: @Koushik Could you please share a screenshot of the error you are seeing?

Comment: I added the screenshot please take a look

Comment: Can you share your manifest file?

Comment: This does not look like an error in App Studio it looks like you are facing some issue while adding a config tab. Could you please share the exact steps you are trying?